# Testing fixtures when using webservices

Tags: tdd

I'm still very new at TDD, and I am also trying to work with a legacy application that was not built with testing in mind.

One feature (bug) I am trying to test is identifying whether an order is in a state allowing a user to schedule delivery.

The story is: given an order with a ReadyFrom date > 10 days and < 28 days from today, where [a webservice to test the order is in a valid state for delivery] returns true the system should list 7 available delivery dates starting from the ReadyFrom date

So I identified some orders suitable for testing these conditions. I think I should also make a stub for the web service, so it returns true or false depending on the test.

I wrote a failing test, and using that I fixed the bug using a copy of the live database, the problem is that next week, the orders I've been using will no longer satisfy some of the conditions, which are based on the system date.

Am I right in thinking I should put the test orders into a fixture and dynamically alter the relevant date values on these orders during the setup, before using them in the test, and dynamically change my expectations of the set of delivery dates the system sends back (the delivery dates are also returned by a web service, which would have to be mocked too)

Or would this invite problems as the application develops?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use the test data builder pattern for creating test data and set it up in the test method itself. IMHO it makes very readable test code. The builder it self goes something like this (C# + Rhinomocks):

```
public class OrderBuilder 
{
  MockRepository _mockRepository;
  IOrder _order;

  public OrderBuilder()
  {
    _mockRepository = new MockRepository();
    _order = _mockRepository.Stub<IOrder>(); 
  }

  public OrderBuilder WithDate(DateTime date)
  {
    _order.Date = date; 
    return this; 
  }

  public IOrder Build()
  {
    _mockRepository.ReplayAll();
    return _order; 
  }

}
```

In the test method the order is created with this syntax:

```
DateTime someValidDate = new DateTime(1,2,2012);

IOrder order = new OrderBuilder()
                      .WithDate(someValidDate)
                      .Build();
```

Isn't that pretty? :o)

Comment: I'll investigate this some more, I think I understand the concept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Put the test orders into a fixture

Yes.

> dynamically alter the relevant date values on these orders during the setup

Sort of.

Don't make it too complex-sounding.  The Fixture should have a bunch of test orders with fixed, known dates.  You shouldn't have to alter too much.

If -- for some reason -- the dates can't be fixed, known dates, then setUp does three things.

1. Builds orders "from scratch" with appropriate dates.
2. Configures the mock with appropriate dates.
3. Saves some "expected results" hint for the actual tests to be used.

Again.  Don't make it sound complex.  You're not "dynamically change my expectations".  You're just setting the expectations in setUp.

> dynamically change my expectations of the set of delivery dates the system sends back 
>   (the delivery dates are also returned by a web service, which would have to be mocked too)

Mocking the web service means the dates could be fixed.  The mock and the fixture should be able to return one, fixed set of dates.